# Polynomial approximation on affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $V,W \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be two affine varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero and let $a,b\in k$.

**Q:** Can we find a polynomial $f \in k[X_1,...,X_n]$ such that $f \equiv a$ on $V$ and $f\equiv b$ on $W$ ?

This is clearly possible if $a=b$ or if one of the varieties is finite. So the interesting case is $a\neq b$ and $\dim V, \dim W \ge 1$.

Of course, if $a \neq b$ then the question is only of interest if $V, W$ are disjoint (for, if $V \cap W\neq \emptyset$ then a solution implies $a = f|_{V\cap W}=b$).

Note: The question has rised from another question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203347/total-degree-of-a-polynomial#203347 and I posted it after googling but without much thinking. So, if it is not appropriate for MO, please migrate it to SE.

Comment: I think you are mistaken $V$, $W$ could be unbounded. I am seeking a $f$ in a bounded region (some subset of $V,W$).

Comment: I know. Therefore I posted this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly impossible if $V \cap W \neq \varnothing$.

Assume otherwise. Then $V \cup W$ is a disjoint union, and $\mathcal{O}(V \cup W) = \mathcal{O}(V) \times \mathcal{O}(W)$.

Since $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^n) \to \mathcal{O}(V \cup W)$ is surjective, we can therefore find $f \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^n)$ such that $f |_V = a$ and $f |_W = b$.

Algebraically, this is just the Chinese remainder theorem for general rings. Let $R$ be a $k$-algebra, and $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $R$. If $I + J \neq R$, then there cannot be a solution to $r \equiv a \pmod{I}$ and $r \equiv b \pmod{J}$ whenever $a,b$ are distinct scalars, because that would imply $a \equiv b \pmod{I+J}$, and thus $a=b$ (this is the only point where the $k$-algebra assumption is used). But if $I+J = R$, then $R/(I+J) \cong R/I \times R/J$.

Comment: @tj_: I fail to see how a *proof* that the answer is yes (when $V \cap W = \varnothing$) counts as nitpicking and fails to be an answer.

Comment: Sorry, your writing is missunderstanding. I interpreted the phrase "Assume otherwise." that you are going to prove the aforementioned statement ("impossible if $V \cap W \neq \emptyset$") by contradiction. Also I don't understand your application of the Chinese remainder theorem: Let $\mathcal{O}(V)=R/I$ and $\mathcal{O}(W)=R/J, R=k[X_1,...,X_n]$. How can I see $I + J = R$ ?

Comment: OK, now I understand: The condition $V \cap W = \emptyset$ implies $I + J = R$ by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. Take $F \in I, G \in J$ with $F+G = 1$. Then $f=bF+aG$ is a solution. Thanks for the answer.